# ORA-00936: missing expression bad SQL grammar

Tags: sql, oracle, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

When i am executing my method i am getting this message in my log file:

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [DELETE FROM DEVICES WHERE DEVICEID IN ([3715, 3716]) ]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression

Can anyone help please?

```
    public int removeDevice(ArrayList<Long> deviceId) {


    StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer("DELETE FROM DEVICES ");

    query.append("WHERE DEVICEID IN ("+deviceId+") ");


    int rowsRemoved = 0;
    try {
        rowsRemoved = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().update(query.toString());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        log.error("query: " + query.toString());

    }
    return rowsRemoved;
```

}

Comment: Perhaps `deviceId.toString()` returns `[3715,3716]`.. it has to be just `3715,3716` . So change your logic to form a comma separated string

Comment: [It does](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()). So you would need to put each value from the list in one by one, separated by commas, in a loop; or preferably change the procedure to take a nested table argument and pass in an ARRAY based on that SQL type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps `deviceId.toString()` returns `[3715,3716]`.. it has to be just `3715,3716` . So change your logic to form a comma separated string

```
query.append("WHERE DEVICEID IN ("+ deviceId.toString().replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "") +") ");
```

This should help! Sorry not tested! This removes the Square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
StringBuilder args = new StringBuilder();
for (Long device : deviceId) {
    args.append(device + ",");
}

StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer("DELETE FROM DEVICES ");

query.append("WHERE DEVICEID IN ("+args.toString().substring(0, args.toString().length() - 1) +") ");
```

Comment: substring takes only int values but how you are passing it StringBuilder

Comment: @user3548196 I didn't understand you. StringBuilder.toString() returns the string value, so then I call length() against this value.